# Serializing dates

Tags: datetime, 8

In Drupal, we have the time printed as `"2012-03-19 07:22"`.

What I need is just `"\/Date(1198908717056)\/"` or just `"1198908717056"`.

I am trying to get that format using the following code.

```
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

$result =[
  [1402963200000, 92.08],
  [1403049600000, 92.18],
  [1403136000000, 91.86],
  [1403222400000, 90.91],
  [1403481600000, 90.83],
];

return new JsonResponse($result);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Generally, dates are already stored as Unix timestamps (which is what I believe you are hoping for). They are only displayed in human-readable formats on the front end.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now, I know the name of format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format what I needed was called Unix timestamps and Drupal already have him.

In php you need just to write something like this:

```
'time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
'unix' => date("U"),
```

More about time format you can found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Also, [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/unix_time_conversion) was useful for me to check if all was good.

Settings for view are the some, just like on photo.

After some testing, it was not Unix. It is unix*1000. XD

[image]